# Elegant design for Angular2/Spring-boot/Restful application

Tags: spring, rest, angular, spring-boot

I'm actually working on a project that uses the following technologies:
Angular 2,
Rest,
Spring boot.

And I'd like to know some good practices for this kind of applications for the two scenarios since this is my first project using theses together:

**1. Validations:**

Example

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>("email", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
return new ResponseEntity<String>("username", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
return new ResponseEntity<UserDto>(userDto, HttpStatus.OK);
```

And in the angular part I'm parsing the answer as this:

```
  addUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        , 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token_string')
      }
    );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.url, user, options) // ...using post request
      .map((res: Response) => {
       // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
        return { status: res.status, body: res.text() };
      })
      .catch((error: any) => { //...errors if any
        return Observable.throw({ status: error.status, body: error.text() });
      }
      );
  }
```

The problem is that when I want to differ between the errors I do as the following which I think is a bad solution to approach this:

```
this.userService.addUser(user).subscribe(
          response => {
            ....
          },
          error => {
            if (error.status == 401) {
              if (error.body === "username") {
                this.usernameAlreadyUsed = true;
                this.emailAlreadyUsed = false;
              }
              if (error.body === "email") {
                this.emailAlreadyUsed = true;
                this.usernameAlreadyUsed = false;
              }
               .....
```

**2. ResponseEntity**

Is there a better way ? a cleaner that will make the Rest controllers cleaner ?

Comment: What kind of errors do you want to distinguish? Different statuses (i.e. consider `401` from your example as Validation, and show general error message for rest statuses) or different error body contents? In first case, you can create your own HTTP service, that has something like `ResultInterceptor`. Handle all statuses except of `401` there... Second case completely depends on your implementation. I don't really think you can make it completely generic. If you use Rective Forms, you can write function that map response object to form field names and sets errors to those fields...

Comment: So I create my custom ResponseEntity with the form I want and then create the same class on the backend so I have a mutual format where I can send precise information and well organized?

Comment: In general - yes, that approach I use. I assume you use `usernameAlreadyUsed` for showing error messages in UI. Instead of that, you can use `*ngIf="form.controls['email'].valid"`. Last problem - generically map response to form. Say backend returns `{status: "validation", field: "email", errorCode: "user.emailExists"}`. Then in generic function do `form.controls[fieldName].setErrors({backend: {message: this.translationService.getMessage(errorCode)}})`... Then you just have to call 1 function from each request `.subscribe(() => {}, (error) => handleFormError(error.json(), this.form))`

Comment: I get it now, this is a better approach.. thank you. Your approach is the solution I wanted !